# how to make round corners for <fieldset> using html with out using any images

Tags: html

how to make round corners for fieldset using html with out using any images

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded corners on DIVs without using images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356756/rounded-corners-on-divs-without-using-images)

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting CSS3-enabled Web browsers, you can use border-radius CSS rule.

Check this article:

- http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it without images is to use CSS3, which will work for all modern browsers (even IE9). It is really simple.

```
fieldset{
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px; /*Just to prevent the content from being to close to the corner*/
}
```

You can even just target specific corners in the way

Comment: good answer, but a bit lacking since only specific browsers will be able to use border-radius(IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera) for ff3 and earlier, you need -moz-border-radius and earlier chrome/safari version also use -webkit-border-radius :)

Comment: True. thanks for the correction. As a side note -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius should inserted before the border-radius property.